# What is the difference between f(x) and x?

Tags: functions

What is the difference between f(x) and x?

For example:

Would

*T*$_1$(*N*) = *O*(*f*(*N*))

be any different than

*T*$_1$(*N*) = *O*(*N*)

?

Note: when I use "*O*" I am using it to indicate big-Oh notation.

Comment: Ummm.... what's the difference between $x$ and $\cos (x)$ or $x^x$?????

Comment: corrected issue with second line

Comment: So what is $T_1$?????   This question is a mess!

Comment: More generally and using pedantic but precise notation: if $g \in O(h)$ then $g\in O(f\circ h)$ if, for instance, $O(h) \subset O(f\circ h)$ but this is not necessary, just sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple example, let $f(x)=x^2$.  Then $T_1(N)=O(f(N))$ says $T_1(N)=O(N^2)$, which is different from $T_1(N)=O(N)$

Comment: In my opinion, the only way OP could ask this question is if he was confused about what big O actually means. It may help to elaborate a little there, but it would be ideal if OP would also elaborate on his confusion.

Comment: @AlfredYerger:  I agree, but I have a strong bias to answer the questions as asked. Sometimes this helps OP clarify his/her thinking.